# Prove the following definite integrals as limits of sum $\int_a^b \frac{1}{x^2}dx = 1/a - 1/b$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

My attempt so far ..

$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim \sum_{1}^{n} h f(a+rh) $, where n tends to infinity, $nh = b-a$

Here $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ , using this we get

$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim \sum_{r=1}^{n^2} h f(a+rh) = \lim h [\frac{1}{(a+h)^2}+\frac{1}{(a+2h)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(a+nh)^2}]$

I cannot proceed further. can someone help?

Comment: enclose your formulas with dollars \$...\$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "$\lim \sum_{r=1}^{n^2} h f(a+rh)$": 1) why $n^2$ and not $n?$+ 2) how are $n$ and $h$ related? + 3) limit as who tends to what? Same questions 2 and 3 for the last expression.

Comment: It is better to use the general Riemann sum $\sum_{k=1}^n f(t_k) (x_k-x_{k-1})$ where $t_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]$ is chosen suitably as $t_k=\sqrt{x_{k-1}x_k}$.